# JQuery Show/Hide issue

Tags: jquery

I have a few links that change content in a Div upon click. Now, one of the links has new content and I am trying to replace the existing div with a new one as follows

```
var terms = document.getElementsByClassName("tos")[0];
var faqs = document.getElementsByClassName("faq")[0];
$(terms).click(function(){
 $("#menuitem").hide();
 $("#newterms").show();
});
$(faqs).click(function(){
 $("#newterms").hide();
 $("#menuitem").show();
});
```

The idea is to hide #newterms when any link other than 'terms' is clicked.

The above code hides #newterms altogether and does not show the new div when I click on 'terms'. I'm not familiar with JQuery and not sure what I am doing wrong. It would be great if any of you can help me out with this.

Sorry, here is the HTML

```
<div id="contenttext">
 <div id="menuitem"></div>
 <div id="newterms">
  <p id="terms_header">Header</p>
  <div id="termsconds">Terms</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I did some search and found that classnames can be accessed this way (above).

Comment: Please show your HTML. Are you intentionally only targeting the first instance of .tos and .faq?

Comment: If you are using jQuery you should also use it for the selectors, ie `$('.tos')` and `$('.faq')`.

Comment: I don't see .tos or .faq in your HTML (or any links, period). Yes, you can access classes that way, but it's needlessly clumsy if you have jQuery available.

Comment: The .tos and .faq are coming in from another page that I am unable to edit. All I have is a template file to which I can add Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery selectors, here is a working JSFiddle. When selecting elements via jQuery a `#` or 'hash' is for the `ID` attribute where as the `.` or 'period' is for the `class` attribute.

So `$('.class-name');` or `$('#id-name');`

http://jsfiddle.net/GdSWX/1/

HTML

```
<a class="tos" href="#">TOS</a>
<br>
<a class="faq" href="#">FAQ</a>

<div id="contenttext">
    <div id="menuitem">menu item</div>
    <div id="newterms">
        <p id="terms_header">Header</p>
        <div id="termsconds">Terms</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var terms = $('.tos');
var faqs = $('.faq');

$(terms).click(function () {
    $("#menuitem").hide();
    $("#newterms").show();
});

$(faqs).click(function () {
    $("#newterms").hide();
    $("#menuitem").show();
});
```

If you initially want to hide one of the two then perform the hide/show after the document has fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newterms").hide();
    $("#menuitem").show();
});
```

Comment: @ultimatecoder Please accept it as the correct answer otherwise it shows up in the unanswered list :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way by hiding your divs you want hidden on page load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#newterms").hide();

$(".tos").click(function () {
    $("#menuitem").hide();
    $("#newterms").show();
    return false;
});

$(".faq").click(function () {
    $("#newterms").hide();
    $("#menuitem").show();
    return faslse;
});
```

});